# Display laravel blade in repository pattern

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-blade, repository-pattern

In my Laravel application, I have the following index function in the `PostController.php`

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
    private PostRepositoryInterface $postRepository;

    public function __construct(PostRepositoryInterface $postRepository)
    {
        $this->postRepository = $postRepository;
    }
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(): JsonResponse
    {
        return response()->json([
            'data' => $this->postRepository->getAllPosts()
        ]);
    }
}
```

Now, I want to display the data on my view called, `posts.blade.php`

Since I'm new to repository patterns on Laravel I'm struggling to call my view file from the controller.

How can I display my view file and display the JSON data in that view?

This is my `web.php`

```
Route::get('posts', [PostController::class, 'index']);
```

Comment: Do you just want to pass your data to view ?

Comment: passing the data and and how to call the view file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined the `route` in `web.php` suggesting you're accessing this `route` via a web browser, yet your `index` function has a `JsonResponse` return type. Remove that return type as you won't be returning `Json`.

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
    private PostRepositoryInterface $postRepository;

    public function __construct(PostRepositoryInterface $postRepository)
    {
        $this->postRepository = $postRepository;
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('index', [
            'data' => $this->postRepository->getAllPosts()
        ]);
    }
}
```

**N.B.**

Personally I would do away with the repository and instead leverage `Eloquent` (part of the beauty and simplicity of Laravel). I feel it is one of those design patterns people blindly implement because they read an article or watched a YouTube video where someone said they should be using it. What is the likelihood you will ever change the underlying datasource for this project, is it just a redundant abstraction that does nothing but add implementation and maintenance overhead?

Comment: I agree to what you said about the repository pattern ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
public function index()
{
   $data = $this->postRepository->getAllPosts();

   if(request()->expectsJson){
      return response()->json([
      'data' => $data
      ]);
   }

   return view('VIEW_NAME', ['data' => $data]);
}
```

Comment: no,this still show sme the raw json output...

Comment: Where you are calling the route? Postman or browser ?

Comment: I'm calling them through the browser